# Gulp (via ts-node) Returning 'void' But Expects 'Task' - Type 'Task' Not Found

Tags: typescript, types, gulp

Could someone please help a poor (gulp/typescript) noob with a typescript-&-gulp.js-related issue?

So I'm running the latest versions of *everything* (node, ts-node, gulp, ts, @types/gulp, etc). Gulp is running under/via ts-node (so with a `gulpfile.ts` instead of `gulpfile.js`) and I'm getting the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'TaskFunction'.
Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(done: TaskCallback): void | EventEmitter | ChildProcess | Stream | Observable<any> | PromiseLike<any>'.
```

My (relevant) code is:

```
gulp.parallel(
    subTask("directory_1"),
    subTask("directory_2")
);

async function subTask(sDirectory:string){
    await gulp.src("src/"+sDirectory+"/*.*")
        // Stuff happens here like linting, transpiling, uglifing, etc
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dest/"+sDirectory+"/"));
    return;
}
```

The code works when I *explicitly* hard code the directory-strings into `subTask` (ie having two copies of the `subTask` => `subTask_1` and `subTask_2`) but not when I parametrize `subTask`.

I understand that I'm returning a `void` promise from `subTask` and gulp is expecting a type of `Task` (being a derivative of `TaskFunction`), but I can't work out what type to give to `subTask` (giving `subTask` a type of `Task` results in `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Task'`; similarly for type `TaskFunction`).

So what am I doing wrong? And, more importantly, how do I fix it (ie can I please have some example code that'll fix my issue).

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Cheers

Dulux-Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your function: the first one is that it returns nothing, the other one is that it is declared as `async`. While gulp streams work *asynchronously*, they are not promises, so they don't have to be awaited, and without `await` there is no need for `async`.

So I would suggest that you change your function to this:

```
function subTask(sDirectory:string) {
    return function() {
        return gulp.src("src/"+sDirectory+"/*.*")
        // Stuff happens here like linting, transpiling, uglifing, etc
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dest/"+sDirectory+"/"));
    };
}
```

The rest of your code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that.
So I refactored as you suggested and am now getting the following error:

```error TS2345: Argument of type 'ReadWriteStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
Type 'ReadWriteStream' is not assignable to type 'TaskFunction'.
Type 'ReadWriteStream' provides no match for the signature '(done: TaskCallback): void | EventEmitter | ChildProcess | Stream | Observable<any> | PromiseLike<any>'.```

Comment: @Dulux-Oz My bad! I missed wrapping the stream into a function. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer given by @goto-0 is 99% correct (and thank you *very* much @goto-0). However, once I had refactored as suggested I ended up with a `Did you forget to signal async completion?` error.

The full, working solution is to make the sub-function inside `subTask` an asyncronous function:

```
function subTask(sDirectory:string) {
    return async function() {
        return gulp.src("src/"+sDirectory+"/*.*")
        // Stuff happens here like linting, transpiling, uglifing, etc
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dest/"+sDirectory+"/"));
    };
}
```

So, all now good :-)